# Clarifying my understanding of how properties are passed (and how useEffect works)

Tags: reactjs

I will not paste all the code - this would make this post huge, I'll explain my issue and paste in snippets to try and keep the post length reasonable.

I have a page which (inside a `useEffect`) goes to Firebase and gets a bunch of data and stores these in state

```
  const [problem_SText, setProblemSText] = useState("")

  useEffect(() => {    
    
    const getFirebase = async () => {
      const snapshot = await firestore.collection(collectionId).doc(documentId).get();
      const questionData = snapshot.data();   
      setProblemSText(questionData.balances.balances.hint.video.video_1.title)
}
```

I then pass that (as a property) to a component to be used later on

```
            <HintComponent 
              auth={props.auth}
              titleCol={hintTitle}
              genCol={genColTitle}
              prob_s_txt={problem_SText}
```

And within the HintComponent, I call a modal:

```
<button className="buttonGeneral" onClick={()=>setShowModalProblemS_vid(true)}>VIDEO</button> 
<VideoModal showModal={showModalProblemS_vid} onClose={() => setShowModalProblemS_vid(false)} videoMessage={props.prob_s_vid} size='med' auth={props.auth} txt={props.prob_s_txt}/>
```

What confused me was that when I got to the modal, something which I was retrieving was appearing as empty.  So I traced this back to the beginning by the use of console.logs

For example, in QuestionPage, I put the console.log within my return() block, so I could see the "final" state.

```
  return (    
    <div className="container">
        {console.log('\n\n\nQuestion Page: ', problem_SText)}
...
```

What I have found in the console is that I have 22 repetitions of the console.log statement, and if I look in the code (which isn't here in full) I set 21 states.

So, this suggests to me that I am not using either state or the `useEffect` hook correctly.  My intention was, essentially, to call `getFirebase` and then set my states, however, as I've done this inside `useEffect`, this seems to refresh a lot more - and this, to me, seems wrong.

I will post the full QuestionPage code under here for context, but the more I look, the more I think this is hugely inefficient and just wrong. Is there an alternative?

---

```
import AnswerComponent from "../components/AnswerComponent";
import HintComponent from "../components/HintComponent";
import QuestionComponent from "../components/QuestionComponent";
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import 'firebase/compat/auth';
import { unstable_batchedUpdates } from "react-dom";

function QuestionPage(props) {
  const firestore = firebase.firestore();
  const collectionId = "Questions";
  const documentId = "balances" 

  const [questionTitle, setQuestionTitle] = useState();

  // question things
  const [questionText, setQuestionText] = useState("");
  const [imageUrl, setImageUrl] = useState("");

  // answer things
  const [answers, setAnswers] = useState([]);
  const [totalAnswers, setTotalAnswers] = useState(0);


  // hint things
  const [hintTitle, setHintTitle] = useState("");
  const [genColTitle, setGenColTitle] = useState("");
  const [specColTitle, setSpecColTitle] = useState("");

  // states to handle hints
  const [problem_SVideo, setProblem_SVideo] = useState("")
  const [problem_SImage, setProblem_SImage] = useState("")
  const [problem_SText, setProblemSText] = useState("")

  const [spec_strat_balan_sVideo, setSpec_strat_balan_sVideo] = useState("")
  const [spec_strat_balan_sImage, setSpec_strat_balan_sImage] = useState("")

  const[mom_sVideo, setMom_sVideo] = useState("")
  const[mom_sImage, setMom_sImage] = useState("")

  const[specMom_sVideo, setSpecMom_sVideo] = useState("")
  const[specMom_sImage, setSpecMom_sImage] = useState("")

  const[gravity_sVideo, setGravity_sVideo] = useState("")
  const[gravity_sImage, setGravity_sImage] = useState("")

  const[specGravity_sVideo, setSpecGravity_sVideo] = useState("")
  const[specGravity_sImage, setSpecGravity_sImage] = useState("")

  useEffect(() => {    
    
    const getFirebase = async () => {
      const snapshot = await firestore.collection(collectionId).doc(documentId).get();
      const questionData = snapshot.data();     

      unstable_batchedUpdates(() => {

        // question component information
        // get and set the question title
        setQuestionTitle(questionData.balances.balances.questions.title)

        // get and set the question text and image
        setQuestionText(questionData.balances.balances.fullquestion.question) 
        setImageUrl(questionData.balances.balances.fullquestion.imageUrl) 

        // answer component info
        // create a new answer array
        const answerArr = []; 
        let selectedAnswers = 0 

        // add the answer from firestore to the answerArr
        Object.keys(questionData.balances.balances.answers).forEach(key => {        
          const obj = questionData.balances.balances.answers[key]

          // will need to know which document the database holds the chosen info, so let's add it to the array
          obj['key'] = key
          answerArr.push(obj);         

          // count the number of times answers were "picked", (i.e. chosen)
          selectedAnswers += questionData.balances.balances.answers[key].chosen
        });
        // set the answers to be the answersArray
        setAnswers(answerArr) 
        setTotalAnswers(selectedAnswers)

        // hint component info
        // get and set hint title 
        setHintTitle(questionData.balances.balances.hint.titleColumn.title_1.columnTitle)
        
        // get and set general column title 
        setGenColTitle(questionData.balances.balances.hint.titleColumn.title_2.columnTitle)

        // get and set problem specific column title 
        setSpecColTitle(questionData.balances.balances.hint.titleColumn.title_3.columnTitle)

        // problem_s 
        setProblem_SVideo(questionData.balances.balances.hint.video.video_1.videoUrl)
        setProblem_SImage(questionData.balances.balances.hint.video.video_1.image)
        setProblemSText(questionData.balances.balances.hint.video.video_1.title)

        // spec_strat_balan_s
        setSpec_strat_balan_sVideo(questionData.balances.balances.hint.video.video_2.videoUrl)
        setSpec_strat_balan_sImage(questionData.balances.balances.hint.video.video_2.image)

        // mom_s
        setMom_sVideo(questionData.balances.balances.hint.video.video_3.videoUrl)
        setMom_sImage(questionData.balances.balances.hint.video.video_3.image)

        // spec_mom_s
        setSpecMom_sVideo(questionData.balances.balances.hint.video.video_4.videoUrl)
        setSpecMom_sImage(questionData.balances.balances.hint.video.video_4.image)

        // gravity_s
        setGravity_sVideo(questionData.balances.balances.hint.video.video_5.videoUrl)
        setGravity_sImage(questionData.balances.balances.hint.video.video_5.image)

        // spec_gravity_s
        setSpecGravity_sVideo(questionData.balances.balances.hint.video.video_6.videoUrl)
        setSpecGravity_sImage(questionData.balances.balances.hint.video.video_6.image)
      })
    }
    getFirebase();    
    }, [firestore]
  );  
      
  return (    
    <div className="container">
        {console.log('\n\n\nQuestion Page: ', problem_SText)}
        <h1 className="text-center">{questionTitle} problem</h1>
        <div className="row">            
            <QuestionComponent 
              auth={props.auth}
              image={imageUrl} 
              text={questionText}
            />
            <HintComponent 
              auth={props.auth}
              titleCol={hintTitle}
              genCol={genColTitle}
              specCol={specColTitle}
              prob_s_im={problem_SImage}
              prob_s_vid={problem_SVideo}
              prob_s_txt={problem_SText}

              spec_strat_bala_s_im={spec_strat_balan_sImage}
              spec_strat_bala_s_vid={spec_strat_balan_sVideo}
              
              mom_s_im={mom_sImage}
              mom_s_vid={mom_sVideo}
              
              specMom_s_im={specMom_sImage}
              specMom_s_vid={specMom_sVideo}
              
              grav_s_im={gravity_sImage}
              grav_s_vid={gravity_sVideo}
              
              spec_grav_s_im={specGravity_sImage}
              spec_grav_s_vid={specGravity_sVideo}
            />
        </div>
        <div className="row">
            <AnswerComponent />
        </div>
    </div> 
  )
}

export default QuestionPage;
```

Modal

```
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import Modal from 'react-bootstrap/Modal';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import 'firebase/compat/firestore';
import 'firebase/compat/storage';

function VideoModal({showModal = false, onClose = () =>{}, videoMessage, size, txt}) {
  
  const firestore = firebase.firestore();

  const [confused, setConfused] = useState(false)
  const [text, setText] = useState("");
  const [video, setVideo] = useState("")

  // console.log("Video Modal ", txt)
  return (
    <Modal
      size={size}
      show={showModal} 
      onHide={onClose}
      onClose={()=>setConfused(false)}
      backdrop="static"
      keyboard={false}
    >

    
    <Modal.Body>
      {console.log("Video Modal ", txt)}
      <video src={videoMessage} controls autoPlay></video> 
      <div>     
        {confused ? (
        <form onSubmit={async (e) => {
          e.preventDefault();
          console.log("submit clicked")
          const timestamp = Date.now()
          const content = text;
          const confusedVideo = video // no wrong
          const uuid = 'blah'

          const message = {content, timestamp, uuid}    
          console.log(message) 
          const docRef = await firestore.collection('problem_s').add(message);
          setText('')     
          
        }}>
          <div>
            What have you found confusing about this video?
            <textarea className='confusedText' 
                      rows="2"
                      value={text}
                      onChange={(value) => {
                        setText(value.target.value);
                      }}>
            </textarea>          
            <Button className="confusedBtnSave" type='Submit'>
              Savez
            </Button>
            <Button className="confusedBtnCancel" onClick={()=>setConfused(false)}>
              Cancel
            </Button>          
          </div>
          </form>
        ) : (
        <div>
          <Button className="confusedBtn" onClick={()=>setConfused(true)}>
            Confused?
          </Button>
        </div>
      )}
      </div>
      
    </Modal.Body>
    <Modal.Footer>
      <Button variant="secondary" onClick={() => {onClose(); setConfused(false)}}>
        Close
      </Button>
    </Modal.Footer>
  </Modal>
  )
}

export default VideoModal
```

Answer (score 1):

Note: the following answer is for react 17 and earlier. React 18 will make this obsolete.

React *attempts* to batch multiple calls to setState into a single render, but in some cases it can't do so. One of the cases where react can't batch changes is in an `async` function after an `await`. So when you call `setQuestionTitle(questionData.balances.balances.questions.title)`, react will *immediately* rerender with that new title. All the other state values have their old value still. Then after that you'll call `setQuestionText(questionData.balances.balances.fullquestion.question)`  and it will immediately render again, and so on.

You can fix this by telling react to batch all these set states together:

```
import { unstable_batchedUpdates } from 'react-dom'; // <--- note, react-dom, not react

// ...
const getFirebase = async () => {
  const snapshot = await firestore.collection(collectionId).doc(documentId).get();
  const questionData = snapshot.data();     

  unstable_batchedUpdates(() => {
    setQuestionTitle(questionData.balances.balances.questions.title)
    setQuestionText(questionData.balances.balances.fullquestion.question) 

    // ...
  });
}
```

The "unstable" in the name of the function is pointing out the fact that this function is not meant to be part of react forever. It is a stopgap that they added to react until they could finish concurrent mode, which is coming in react 18. `unstable_batchedUpdates` will continue to exist in react 18, but won't be necessary, and they intend to remove it in some future version.

Comment: I highly doubt that React would schedule a full update _immediately_ between the `setQuestionTitle` and `setQuestionText` calls.

Comment: @AKX And yet, it does. Minimal example: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-odjiij?file=/index.js

Comment: Apologies - I did forget to include my react version in the question (currently on 17.0.2)

Comment: @NicholasTower - and suddenly 20+ console logs become 2, that is very very interesting., not sure if it's going to fix my issues - but that is a very well written answer

Comment: @NicholasTower one thing which does confuse me.  Following the logic from above.  QuestionPage sets a bunch of states, which are then passed into various components, I can see one of these states going to a modal, but then that state gets overwritten with nothing.  As the states are passed as props - this confuses me - I've updated the question with the code to show this

Comment: Sorry, i don't see anything that would cause that problem

Comment: @NicholasTower Um... are you sure that was the correct sandbox link?

Comment: Huh, sorry about that. Try this one: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-l77p2l?file=/index.js

Comment: @NicholasTower Thanks. I guess I was confusing that with how React defers/batches DOM updates :)

Comment: @NicholasTower Without the async function, though, there is only a single re-render with both states having changed.

Comment: Correct, react attempts to batch updates when it can. The `async` function (or more specifically, the `await`) breaks its ability to do so. In react 18, it will batch all updates.